# IR transmitter for Air Conditioner using PC Serial Port

Tags: c#, serial-port, infrared

I have to control an air conditioner from pc serial port using IR LED, When I am reading the IR data from the serial port It gives nearly 160 characters, But actually my AC remote may send a address+command it may be 8 to 32 bit only. So I would like to know how to decode the IR data using only Serial port. Right now I am using C# code for reading the data. When I am using Terminal also it gives the same data.

The data is as follows:
ððpppððppððpðpðpðpppppppppppppðððpppppppððpððpðppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppð
ðððøðxpxøøxxøøxøxðxðxppppppxpxpppðøøxxxxxxxøøxøøxøxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xx

This is for ON button..

Please help me....

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_IR

Answer (score 1):

As a software developer I look at 'what is the intent'. So in this case I wonder if the intent is to control the air conditioner rather than write the code. :-)

If so, you may take the approach of use one of the many home automation products to capture the IR command and have your software trigger that 'saved' command.

"The fastest way to do something is to not do it at all" - Alister Cockburn.

If this is of any interest have a look at these:

- http://www.redrat.co.uk/
- http://www.usbuirt.com/
- http://www.uk-automation.co.uk/products/SQ-IR-%28Infrared%29-Blaster.html

Good luck

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Serial communications are always done at a particular speed, or *baud rate*. It sounds like you may not be reading the data at the correct baud rate. Do you know what the baud rate is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the baud rate is incorrect. 9600 is the most common for these kind of devices so make sure your serial port is set to that. Otherwise try all of them out or find some documentation telling you what it is.